# Сделать лексический анализатор на питон

Tags: python, структуры

Хочу сделать лексический анализатор на питон.Он работает с закоментированным while,как сделать чтобы использовать много токенов:

```
# Program "as if"
#import pdb
#pdb.set_trace()
token_exprs=[(r'do','RESERVED')]
import re
import sys
def lex(characters,token_expr):#characters='do'
        pos=0
        t=[]
#    while pos<len(characters) :#при pos=0
        match=None
        for token_expr in token_exprs:#token_expr=('do', 'RESERVED')
            patern,tag=token_expr#patern='do' tag='RESERVED'
            regex=re.compile(patern)#regex=re.compile('do')
            match=regex.match(characters,pos)#match=<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 2), match='do'>
            if match:# класс True
                text=match.group(0)#text='do'
                if tag:#класс True
                    token=(text,tag)#token=('do','REVERSED')
                    t.append(token)
                break
            if not match:
                 sys.stderr.write('Illegal character:%s\n'% characters[pos])
                 sys.exit(1)
            else:
                 match.end(0)
        return t  


def lex_imp(characters):
  return lex(characters,token_exprs)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(lex_imp('do'))#<---[('do', 'RESERVED')]#Расскоментировать while что бы
    #в lex_imp можно было передать lex_imp(['do','end','\n'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Все решил!)

```
token_exprs=[(r'[ \n\t]+','None'),
             (r'#[^\n]*','None'),
             (r'\:=','RESERVED'),
             (r'\(','RESERVED'),
             (r'\)','RESERVED'),
             (r';','RESERVED'),
             (r'\+','RESERVED'),

             (r'-','RESERVED'),
             (r'\*','RESERVED'),
             (r'/','RESERVED'),
             (r'<=','RESERVED'),
             (r'<','RESERVED'),

             (r'>=','RESERVED'),
             (r'>','RESERVED'),
             (r'!=','RESERVED'),
             (r'=','RESERVED'),
             (r'and','RESERVED'),

             (r'or','RESERVED'),
             (r'not','RESERVED'),
             (r'if','RESERVED'),
             (r'then','RESERVED'),
             (r'else','RESERVED'),

             (r'while','RESERVED'),
             (r'do','RESERVED'),
             (r'end','RESERVED'),
             (r'[0-9]+','INT'),
             (r'[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*','ID'),]

import re
import sys
def lex(characters,token_expr):#characters='do'
   pos=0
   t=[]
   while pos<len(characters) :#при pos=0
        match=None
        for token_expr in token_exprs:#token_expr=('do', 'RESERVED')
                                      #token_exprs=[(r'do','RESERVED')]
            patern,tag=token_expr#patern='do' tag='RESERVED'
            regex=re.compile(patern)#regex=re.compile('do')
            match=regex.match(characters,pos)#match=<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 2), match='do'>
            if match:# класс True
                text=match.group(0)#text='do'
                if tag:#класс True
                    token=(text,tag)#token=('do','REVERSED')
                    t.append(token)#t=[('do', 'RESERVED')]
                break
        if not match:#not None==not False->True->клас True
                 sys.stderr.write('Illegal character:%s\n'% characters[pos])
                 sys.exit(1)
        else:
               pos=match.end()

   #pos+=len(text)         
   return t #t=[('do', 'RESERVED')] 


def lex_imp(characters):
  return lex(characters,token_exprs)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(lex_imp('do  + -'))#
```

Сделал еще схемку его:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]